# LetsEncrypt/CertBot Installed, Chrome Still Not Secure

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

hopefully this is pretty open and shut, but here's the situation.

I used LetsEncrypt and CertBot to set my website www.blueprintstats.com up with an SSL certificate. Now, I realized after the fact that I had to add blueprintstats.com (no www) separately, and made that change. All good!

If you go to these links, you can see that I am in the clear on both:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.blueprintstats.com&hideResults=on

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=blueprintstats.com&hideResults=on

However, when I go to either in Chrome, I am still getting "Not Secure". I read online that unlike DNS changes, these are not cached, and thus that is not the problem.

Does anyone see what is going on here? I even tried restarting apache (no luck).

Comment: if possible show us Screenshots, also tell us what kind of server you use, as it seems to me that your using this site for Private stuff (enduser support) this regards to superuser. com

Answer (score 0):

I needed to redirect http traffic to https. Used this link to figure out how: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/redirect-http-to-https/